# Static method in multi thread web application

Tags: python, multithreading, web-applications, webserver

Let's say I have the following static method inside a web applicaton.

```
@staticmethod
def calc(x, y): 
   # complex calculation
```

This function will always have a copy running the memory. So multiple users hit this function at the same time, does each user have to wait for the function to become available?

I try to understand what's going at the CPU and memory level.